# Using light.exe is there a way to write Config Variables to a log file or text file during the creation of .msi package

Tags: wix, wix3.5

We currently have ConfigVariables.wxi file which we include in our product.wxs file. One of the variables is ProductCode which is an automatically generated GUID

```
  <!-- Auto-generate GUID for ProductCode for each build -->
  <?define ProductCode = "*" ?>
```

Using command line we create the .msi file, during this process I would like to retrieve the ProductCode GUID for use later.

Command line:

```
light.exe Product.wixobj ThirdPartyFile.wixobj CompressFile.wixobj -out 1.0.0\My_Test_Installer2.msi
```

Therefore is there a way I can write config variable to a log file or text, i.e: `$(var.ProductCode)`